# Passing data from WebResponse to different method

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebresponse

I am trying to pass HttpWebResponse data from a method which checks whether web address written by user exists to another method which will use a StreamReader to get the html sourcecode and later working with it but even though it doesn't show any error I am not getting the sourcode written in prepared listbox. There is as well a button click event which I am not including and shouldn't have any impact on the problem.

```
        protected bool ZkontrolujExistenciStranky(string WebovaStranka)
    {
        try
        {
            var pozadavek = WebRequest.Create(WebovaStranka) as HttpWebRequest;
            pozadavek.Method = "HEAD";
            using (var odezva = (HttpWebResponse)pozadavek.GetResponse())
            {
                GetData(odezva);
                return odezva.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;                   
            }

        }
        catch    
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

   protected void GetData(HttpWebResponse ziskanaOdezva)
        {
            using (Stream strm = ziskanaOdezva.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strm);
                string prochazec;
                while ((prochazec = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(prochazec);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: But shouldn't it at least give me the code written in HEAD instead of nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the HEAD method, whose whole point is not to return a body; only headers are returned. Use GET if you want the body.

[HTTP HEAD method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html):

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request.

Comment: Thanks that did the job! I was confused since I expected that HEAD would pass at least some data to the listBox.

Comment: @TomasGryzbon So you are trying to get something from the head tag of the html? That's not what they are referring to when when they are talking about headers and body here. They mean the HTTP headers like Content-Type, Date, Server, etc. The body is the whole html page.

Comment: No I want only the html page source code. Which I got from that, thanks for clearing it up...